# React Hook Form Controller, onChange not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am trying to wrap my component with controller to return some numeric values but in some component onChange for controller is not firing. Not sure, why
Please find the code attached. Thanks in advance

```
const Percentage: FC<PercentageProps & Partial<HTMLInputElement>> = ({ withForm, ...otherProps}) => {
  if(withForm){
    return (
      <FormControl {...otherProps}>
        <Controller
          render={({field: { value, onChange, name }}) => {
            return (
              <PercentageWrapper
                name={name}
                value={value}
                withForm={withForm}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  console.log('inside percentage controller >>>>>>>', e)
                  onChange && onChange(Math.ceil(e.target.value))
                }}
              />
            )
          }}
        >
        </Controller>
      </FormControl>
    )
  }
  return <PercentageWrapper {...otherProps}/>
}
```

This is percentageWrapper to handle the form condition

### PercentageWrapper

```
const PercentageWrapper: FC<PercentageProps & Partial<HTMLInputElement>> = (
  props: PercentageProps
) => {
  // Framework generated code, below line registers the component
  // NOT TO BE DELETED
  setMetaData('Percentage', metadata);

  // Framework generated code, below line provides the contextProvider instance

  const {
    id,
    onChange,
    showPercentSymbol,
    allowDecimalPlaces,
    withForm,
    value,
    ...rest
  } = props;
  return (
    <div data-component="atomic/percentage">
      <Input
        placeholder={'Percent'}
        value={value}
        inputSuffix={
          showPercentSymbol
            ? () => (
                <Text
                  type={TextTypes.Body}
                  size={TextSizes.Medium}
                  marginTop={'2px'}
                >
                  {'%'}
                </Text>
              )
            : undefined
        }
        {...rest}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing `onChange` to the input.

```
const {
    id,
    onChange, // <-- you destructure it here
    showPercentSymbol,
    allowDecimalPlaces,
    withForm,
    value,
    ...rest // <-- so it's not part of the `rest`
  } = props;
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I have resolved the issue